# Avoiding virtual functions on embedded target

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I have a `class Player` that plays back data from a big block of memory that consists of a number of equal chunks.

```
typedef char chunk_t[100];

typedef struct {
    chunk_t data[100]
} blockOfMemory_t;
```

The Player itself could theoretically work for different layouts and contents of data, so I would like to program it in a re-usable way. To do this, I thought of something like this:

```
class Player {
public:
    Player() { ... }
    virtual ~Player() { ... }

    void play() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumChunks(); i++)
        {
           if (chunkHasX(i) || chunkHasY(i))
               playChunk(i);
        }
    }

protected:
    virtual int getNumChunks() = 0;
    virtual bool chunkHasX(int chunkIndex) = 0;
    virtual bool chunkHasY(int chunkIndex) = 0;
    virtual void playChunk(int chunkIndex) = 0;
}
```

By inheriting from this and implementing the data details in the child, I could achieve the re-usability.

However, the target is an ARM Cortex-M4 processor and speed is highly important. For this reason, I would expect to have performance drawbacks when using virtual functions. So I'm looking for a way to achieve the same type of re-usability with an aproach that can be resolved at compile-time and would allow for inlining of `chunkHasX(..)`, etc.

This is screaming "template" - but how would I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I used to work in many projects where performance was important factor and never ever virtual functions were an issue...

Comment: Here is an awesome talk from Sean Parent on just that: [Inheritance Is The Base Class of Evil](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil)

Comment: Well, in your sample there are no virtual functions needed as far I can see, there's no class derived from `Player`. But if you have such situation, the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is a good improvement to avoid the cost of virtual functions.

Comment: My advice would be to not optimize based on what you “would expect”, but to measure first and see what's needed. Honestly, while virtual methods sometimes happen to be an abysmal performance bottleneck, most of the times, you don't even care, given how little impact it has compared to other things.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: In order to have anything useful, I would have to derive a class from `Player`.

I was wondering if there is a way to have something like:
`template<class T> class Player { ... }` and inside the `play()` function use static members of T like this: `T::chunkHasX(i)`. Thus, I could have my re-usability by supplying the `Player` template with a pure static class like this `class TImpl { static bool chunkHasX(int chunkIndex) { ... }; }` 

This looks very similar to the CRTP pattern. On a second thought, CRTP is probably even tidier.

Comment: @user1872293 With CRTP it would look like `template<class Derived> class Player { ... }` and whenever you need to call something from the derived class you use `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();`. This pattern saves space and performance when working on an embedded system.

Comment: Remember that with CRTP you will probably make your code a lot less understandable for the price of performance you probably don't require. Premature optimization is the root of all evil after all ;)

Comment: @rozina: In my case, I have a tight loop that should be processed as quickly as possible. Basically, the player scans through all the memory chunks to find the next one to play - the critical part is that loop.

Comment: If that is the case then it is worth it ofc. However make sure that the function call itself takes comparable time to the actual code inside the function. That is rarely the case unless the function is a one liner that you want to be inlined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have measured and confirmed that the cost of virtual function calls or increased object size makes it desirable to do this. Or perhaps you just think a template design is preferable.

### Inheritance with CRTP

If you want to use inheritance you could use the [Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). You have a templated Player base class where the template parameter is the derived class:

```
template<class Derived>
class Player {
public:
    void play() 
    {
        auto& derived = static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < derived.getNumChunks(); i++)
        {
           if (derived.chunkHasX(i) || derived.chunkHasY(i))
               derived.playChunk(i);
        }
    }
};

class DerivedPlayer : public Player<DerivedPlayer> {
private:
  friend class Player<DerivedPlayer>;
  int getNumChunks();
  bool chunkHasX(int chunkIndex);
  bool chunkHasY(int chunkIndex);
  void playChunk(int chunkIndex);
};

int main() {
    DerivedPlayer p;
    p.play();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kVh9KJ5dUR8m2C4d).

### Composition

Or perhaps you could use composition instead of inheritance and compose your `Player` of a `ChunkHolder` which is passed as a template parameter:

```
template<class ChunkHolder>
class Player {
private:
    ChunkHolder chunk_holder;
public:
    void play() 
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < chunk_holder.getNumChunks(); i++)
        {
           if (chunk_holder.chunkHasX(i) || chunk_holder.chunkHasY(i))
               chunk_holder.playChunk(i);
        }
    }
};

class MyChunkHolder {
public:
  int getNumChunks();
  bool chunkHasX(int chunkIndex);
  bool chunkHasY(int chunkIndex);
  void playChunk(int chunkIndex);
};

int main() {
    Player<MyChunkHolder> p;
    p.play();
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G4sDxRCrw9KCmCyU).

**Update:**
Russ Schultz comment reminded me that if you want to treat these different Players polymorphically, you can. Just introduce an interface:

```
class IPlayer {
public:
  virtual ~IPlayer(){}
  virtual void play() = 0;
};
```

And then in both cases you can inherit from this interface and override the `play()` function:

```
template<class T>
class Player : IPlayer {
public:
    void play() override;
};
```

Now you can, for example, put the players in one container but you don't compromise performance by calling virtual function in inner loops.
Live demo with [CRTP](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bD9p0aOUIJmXRK3Z) and [composition](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3Hdg1PPTqAQiFqqa).

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem of interfaces and abstract classes, does it?

Comment: Thank you for this great and detailed answer, it perfectly solves my issue! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RussSchultz the use of the template parameter specifies an implicit interface.  Of course,  if you want an abstract interface that you can treat polymorphically at runtime then this will not help but OP did not ask for that.

Comment: @RussSchultz I have added an update that might address your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The cost of calling a virtual function vs. a static function is at worst a single lookup.

Each object has a pointer to it's vtable, which has the virtual function pointers in it, so it's something like:

```
ldr [r0,#8],r4 
blx r4
```

instead of

```
ldr #0x400025e5,r4
blx r4
```

or (if the address you need to branch to can be encoded inline)

```
br #0x1035
```

As long as you're not calling a virtual function in your tight loops, it simply isn't a problem.

Comment: "As long as you're not calling a virtual function in your tight loops" - But OP _is_ calling virtual functions in their loop.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I was thinking more of 'for every audio sample' kind of tight loop, not 'for every chunk of many audio samples'

Comment: @ChrisDrew Also note that the compiler has the option to move the vtable lookup outside of the loop.