# How to make unit tests for embedded code?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, embedded, abstraction

I'm working on software for a Cortex-M4 based microcontroller in C++. I have a lot of code (drivers, etc.) that is highly machine dependent. And I have higher level code which is closely dependant on the low level code by using the drivers directly. Example: a low-level part is eg. a UART driver which is very hardware-specific, and a high-level part is a communication protocol which is based on UART. (This software runs on "bare-metal", ie. there is no operating system underneath.)

This code is currently tightly coupled, thus not unit testable.
I'd like to make it testable.

So I figured that I'd create an abstraction of the low-level parts, and make the high-level parts depend only on the abstraction. I could then create mocks of the abstraction which would be used by the unit tests, and a real implementation which would run on the microcontroller.

- Is this a correct approach?
- How can I create such an abstraction?
  Most of the [sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3027/is-c-suitable-for-embedded-systems) [I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478555/avoiding-virtual-functions-on-embedded-target) strongly discourage the use of inheritance and `virtual` functions in embedded systems. What other ways are there?

So, in summary, I'd like to create a hardware abstraction layer (HAL), but I'm asking how to do it? Should I use `virtual` inheritance in C++, or is there another, better way?

Comment: Your abstraction that you suggested would be a Hardware Abstraction Layer which is not uncommon infact perfectly okay. You would define interfaces on each of your HAL's and implement them. For Mocks you simply implement that interface and provide the desired behaviour.

Comment: @SamerTufail Yes, but how do I do that without `virtual` methods?

Comment: I am not sure what you read, please edit and share those sources or the summary. I use interfaces on embedded and have not come across any problems. It depends on your target system and compiler support. If there is something specific against virtuals or inheritance on your target, please share.

Comment: If you don't want to go virtual, you can still have two implementations. Since you never need both simultaneously, instruct your toolchain to build and link the correct implementation.

Comment: @Samer Tufail: The usual argument, aside from performance implications, is that by using function pointers the call graph is no longer static. Therefore rendering static tool-assisted proofs of things such as maximum stack usage and branch coverage difficult in safety-critical systems.

Comment: @doynax: Is it a saftey critical system? If yes then you have a whole diff set of issues as well dynamic memory being top.

Comment: @Samer Tufail: Well, of course. I have no knowledge of the OPs application though.

Comment: Yes.  If your compiler supports C++11, you can use std::function.  But using virtual function is the straight-forward approach.

Answer (score 7):

For C++ I would suggest using an interface so say we have a `HAL.hpp` and in there we define our pure virtual functions we want to implement:

```
class HAL
{
    virtual void func1() = 0;
    virtual void func2() = 0;
};
```

Then you can have your `Mock.cpp` implement this and you can have a Real.cpp implement the same:

```
Mock.cpp:
class Mock : HAL
{
        virtual void func1(){ }
        virtual void func2(){ }
}
```

Now the other way is you define your functions in `HAL.h` like and provide no implementation here:

```
void func1();
void func2();
```

You then create a `HAL.cpp` and add functionality there you wish to see on the target. Create all of this as library called HAL. Link this library to your main project.

Now for mocking and testing. Create a seperate project for your tests. Add the sources you want to test but do not link the HAL library. Instead create another source file Mock.cpp include the HAL.h and provide implementation for it. In this way instead of your functionality from the HAL library the Mock's implementation would be called.

Answer (score 3):

Create the microcontroller HAL in separate files from the mock HAL. For the microcontroller, include the microcontroller HAL sources in your project. For the unit test system, include the mock HAL sources in your project.

You can also test on-target by using compiler macro defines to switch in pieces of the mock HAL, and switch out pieces of the microcontroller HAL.

You can even use your debugger to force values at interface points to trigger all paths; doing this with a code coverage tool will let you know if you've exercised all paths (and MC/DC if you need it). This is sometimes the only way to simulate hardware failures or exceptional conditions.